# Corrupted files uploaded on REST method call

Tags: java, rest, file-upload

So I am using following Rest method in my web application to upload files. When I upload Text files, they are saved properly and i can open them. But in case of any other format i.e. *.docx or *.pdf or *.jpg, the files are stored with exact size as original files but are corrupted. Following is the code:

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response readFile() throws IOException, ServletException {
    Part filePart = request.getPart("c");
    InputStream f = filePart.getInputStream();
    String l = null;
    DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(f);
    File file = new File("c:\\temp\\" + getSubmittedFileName(filePart));
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        while ((l = ds.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(l);
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        return Response.status(201).entity("File Created").build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.status(500).build();
}
```

and the html page as follows:

```
<form action="api/fetch" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="c" name="c" type="file" aria-required="true"><br/><br/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I assume there must be another way to upload files rather than this. i have refereed to [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) but i assume it doesn't say anything about handling file extension. So, what is going wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is here

```
DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(f);
...
while ((l = ds.readLine()) != null) {
```

From [DataInputStream.readLine Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine--)

> This method does not properly convert bytes to characters.

You should use a `FileInputStream` instead of a `DataInputStream`. The `FileInputStream` treat all your files as bytes. Beside the mentioned problem `readLine` would also strip during reading all linebreaks from your input file.

**edit** For demonstration see below small snippet.

The file `dummy.txt` contains

```
foo
bar
```

The linebreak after `foo` is a single `\n`. In a hex dump it is

```
66 6F 6F 0A 62 61 72
```

Now the file is read once using a `DataInputStream` and once with a `FileInputStream`

```
try (DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("dummy.txt"));
        Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out_writer.txt"))) {
    String l;
    while ((l = ds.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write(l);
    }
}
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("dummy.txt");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out_inputstream.txt")) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int readBytes = -1;
    while ((readBytes = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
    }
}
```

The output files are

**out_writer.txt**

```
ASCII: foobar
hex  : 66 6F 6F 62 61 72
```

**out_inputstream.txt**

```
ASCII: foo
       bar
hex  : 66 6F 6F 0A 62 61 72
```

As you can see the `0A` (the `\n`) is stripped in the `DataInputStream` example. And this stipped `line break` garbles your output files.

Comment: works perfectly. thanks for in depth explaination :)