# REST method for image uploading and saving - InputStream processing to image format jpg, png

Tags: rest, jersey, inputstream, multipartform-data, multipart

I am using Jersey (org.glassfish.jersey - version 2.22.2) - JAX-RS, Guice and implementing method for image upload:

```
@PUT
@Path("/image")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ImageResponse putImage(@FormDataParam("image") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {

    writeToFileWithOutputStream(uploadedInputStream);

    return null;
}


private void writeToFileWithOutputStream(InputStream uploadedInputStream) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("xxx.jpg"));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I use write to file with method writeToFileWithOutputStream, I get file which does not open as image. It consists:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary5PVRYeRUBBAFA9yi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="images.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

/** image symbols **/

------WebKitFormBoundary5PVRYeRUBBAFA9yi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""


------WebKitFormBoundary5PVRYeRUBBAFA9yi--
```

If I delete the top 4 lines manually, image opens properly.

I have tried to process them with BufferedReader/Writer but it is malformed because of [Corrupted files uploaded on REST method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588931/corrupted-files-uploaded-on-rest-method-call)

Also tried to use ImageIO.read(inputStream) but it returns null.

What is the best way to process received image InputStream and save it as image (jpg, png or other format)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. code :**
When receiving  an image  with jersey, the  stream received is not a String but a InputStream that you might read:

```
@OPTION
@Path("/image")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response putImag_opts(

@FormDataParam("image") InputStream stream,
@FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){
     return Response.ok().build();
}

@PUT
@Path("/image")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response putImage(

@FormDataParam("image") InputStream stream,
@FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail


) {

    writeToFileWithOutputStream(stream);

    //if ok...
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

**informations:**
-  object `stream` is the stream received,
-  object `fileDetail` contains files informations

**2. dependencies :**
Please also check  that you have the right dependency to upload image :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**3. register in you app class**

Register content multipart in your App.class jersey

```
register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I am experiencing the problem when using InputStream. @FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail - if I don't use FormDataContentDisposition as parameter, it adds additional data to InputStream? Do you process InputStream before saving as image?

Comment: Thanks. I had been already using jersey-media-multipart dependency. I can not add second @FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition parameter because I get com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException. It described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179249/com-sun-jersey-spi-inject-errorserrormessagesexception-severe-missing-depend

Comment: updated response. have you registered in you App Multipart?

Comment: Is there any specific config for Guice?

Comment: this is depending on jersey and not Guice, works with guice or without. But need to be added in you custom Jersey App class.

Comment: The most important part is 3. I think that's what the OP is missing. The request is being treated like a normal request because the multipart provider is not taking care of it.

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
   <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet> does give the same error.

Comment: you  are not using App class but web.xml only configuration? What is the version of the servlet that you use 2 or 3? Can you give me the full version tag please?

Comment: I have tried override "extends Application", web.xml configuration but it does notwork.   <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: My project also includes external jar lib which use Jersey 1.

Comment: what is the version in your Web.xml

Comment: that is you problem, do not use both version of jersey at same time. Is external dependency only client dependency or server dependency? Caution with this, this is a source of problem at runtime!

Comment: @Justas, See [this post for the 2.x jars](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435), if you're not using Maven

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of different Jersey versions - version 1 in external jar lib and Jersey 2 in the main project. Switched to Jersey 1 in the main project, now images are saved and opened properly without additional processing. Also, there is no exception when 2 arguments are used together:

```
@FormDataParam("image") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
@FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
```